# Pass Json Object from ViewHolder to Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have a `RecyclerView` and a `Fragment`. I want to pass a `JSONObject` from `RecyclerView` to `Fragment`. So, I created an Interface and implemented it on `Fragment` and on `RecyclerView`. I initialized the variable and access the method in the fragment passing the `JSONObject` to it, however I am getting a `NPE` when trying to access the method:

```
public class ProductResultsListFragment extends  Fragment implements ProductResultAdapterInterface{
//code here

@Override
public void showResultsInMap(JSONObject mapObject) 
{
    openMapFragment(mapObject);
}
```

In my RV class I have the following:

```
public class ProductSearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductSearchAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

public ProductResultAdapterInterface mProductResultsListener;
  .....

if (mapObjects.length()>0)
{                                         
   mProductResultsListener.showResultsInMap(mapObjects);
}
```

The `if` statement is inside my `viewHolder` in my `RecyclerView` class but the instance is made public.

I have tried casting my mProductResultsListener but dont know what class to cast it into.

```
public ProductResultAdapterInterface mProductResultsListener=((ProductResultAdapterInterface ) ?????);
```

Just a quick comment: the mapObject (JsonObject) is created on a onClick method inside a button in ViewHolder, I cannot pass bundle on OnCreate method.

```
 this.btnMarkItemMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position  =   getAdapterPosition();

                switch (v.getId())
                {
                    case (R.id.markProductinMap):

                        String mapObj=null;
                        if (mapObjects !=null)
                        {
                            String positionDescription=String.valueOf(position);
                            String productLatLngValue=txtProductPrice.getText().toString()+";"+ txtItemLanLong.getText().toString();

                            //tring mapPosition=

                            mapObj=mapObjects.optString(String.valueOf(position));

                            if (mapObj!="") //Button not click remove from map
                            {
                                btnMarkItemMap.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                                btnMarkItemMap.setTag(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                                mapObjects.remove(positionDescription);
                            }
                            else //Button Click add to Map
                            //
                            {
                                btnMarkItemMap.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255, 51, 102));
                                btnMarkItemMap.setTag(position);
                                try {mapObjects.put(positionDescription, productLatLngValue);}catch (JSONException ex){}
                                if (mapObjects.length()>0)
                                {
                                    mProductResultsListener.showResultsInMap(mapObjects);
                                }
                            }

                        }else{
                            mapObjects=new JSONObject();
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

where have you assigned the variable `mProductResultsListener`?
you need to assign this to the object of the fragment by passing it into the adapter. Otherwise its value is null and you will get a `NullPointeException` if you call a function on a null object.

If you have, then please update the question with that code.

Comment: Could have been a comment.

Comment: I think you missed some part of the comment.
@Rohit5k2: I posted it as an answer since it usually makes a short one into a comment on its own. Otherwise I end up pushing incomplete comments if I press enter accidentally while writing one.

Comment: @ImRickJames: why do you need to cast? If the fragment Implements ProductResultAdapterInterface you can just assign it to the variable

Comment: @Mo1989 from what I have been reading when you need to use the callback u need to initialize it so you can use the interface's method in it, in my case the Fragment is implementing the interface and the ViewHolder is accessing the method. I updated my code. thanks!

Comment: @ImRickJames that correct but you can just say mProductResultsListener= myProductResultsListFragment. In case you're passing it as just a fragment and not a ProductResultsListFragment you might need to cast it to one. But I suggest just passing it in directly as a ProductResultAdapterInterface in the constructor or setter in the adapter.

Comment: @Mo1989 see my first answer, I was able to solve it. thanks

Comment: @ImRickJames: I posted it at the exact same time. But I'm glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data using bundles like this

```
SomeFragment someFragment = new SomeFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("value1", "2");
    bundle.putString("value2", "23");
    bundle.putString("value3", "276");
    bundle.putString("value4", "27");
    bundle.putBoolean("flag", true);
    someFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in SomeFragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    strValue1 = bundle.getString("value1");
    strValue2 = bundle.getString("value2");
```

and so on for getting all the passed data from bundle

Comment: Doesn't apply in this case. OP is using `Interface`.

Comment: The basic thing is you should check from the start like Mo1989 said

Comment: Check whether listener is declared and define properly and whether the data that you are passing is not null

Comment: @Aziz the data is not null, but the NPE is coming from mProductResultsListener which is not initialized.

Comment: then initialized it, you got your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductResultsListFragment yourFragment = new ProductResultsListFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("yourJsonObject", yourJsonObject.toString);
yourFragment.setArguments(bundle);

public class ProductResultsListFragment...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle savedInfo = this.getArguments();
        String savedJsonString = savedInfo.getString("yourJsonObject");
        JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(savedJsonString);
//....
```

Comment: The fragment is already created, I want to pass a JsonObject once my fragment is on screen and just want to pass the Object created on my Onclick Method in ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

On my Fragment adapter init, I added:

```
ProductResultAdapterInterface mProInterface=(ProductResultAdapterInterface) this;
        mAdapter = new ProductSearchAdapter(R.layout.product_results_cardlist,getActivity(),productListFeed,mProInterface);
```

on my adapter constructor I changed the signature to accept the Interface as a parameter passed from the Fragment

```
 public ProductSearchAdapter (int rowLayout, Context context,List<Product> feedList,ProductResultAdapterInterface mProductResultsListener) {


        this.feedItemLists=feedList;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mProductResultsListener=mProductResultsListener;

    }
```

Then I was able to access the method and not getting NPE. thanks all